# "Index was not found" program in Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, indexing

I write a program that has a list of numbers. You need to add code to find a specific number in the list. If the number is found, the program will show its location. If the number is not found, the program will say that it couldn't be found.

The problem is, the output is looping, and I don't want that.

```java
int[] array = new int[10];
array[0] = 6;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 8;
array[3] = 1;
array[4] = 3;
array[5] = 0;
array[6] = 9;
array[7] = 7;

System.out.print("Search for? ");
int searching = in.nextInt();

for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(searching == array[i]){
        System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i + ".");
        break;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(searching + " was not found.");
    }
}
```

My output:

```
Search for? 1
1 was not found.
1 was not found.
1 was not found.
1 is at index 3.
```

Expected output:

```
1 is at index 3.
```

Comment: Don't print in the loop. Use `int` to store the index with matching value. Use special value for it meaning **not found**. Print message after the loop depending on the value stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IndexWasNotFound {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[0] = 6;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 8;
        array[3] = 1;
        array[4] = 3;
        array[5] = 0;
        array[6] = 9;
        array[7] = 7;

        int index = 0;
        String ans = null;
        boolean yn;
        System.out.print("Search for? ");
        int searching = scanner.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            if (searching == array[i]) {
                index = i;
                ans = searching + " is at index " + index + ".";
                yn = true;
                break;
            } else {
                ans = searching + " was not found.";
                yn = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```